# using std::set find with struct data

Tags: c++, set, equals, std, comparator

```
typedef struct Edge
{
    int v1, v2, w;
    bool operator <(const Edge &rhs) const{
        bool b = v1 < rhs.v1 || v2 < rhs.v2;
        return (b);
    }
} edge;


template <class T>
struct my_less
{
    bool operator()(const T& _Left, const T& _Right) const
    {
        return (_Left < _Right);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    set <edge, my_less<edge> > F;

    edge e3 = { 3, 3, 3};
    edge e4 = { 3, 7, 3};
    edge e5 = { 2, 7, 3};

    F.insert(e3);
    printf("e3 ? %d\n", F.find(e3)!=F.end()); // O
    printf("e4 ? %d\n", F.find(e4)!=F.end()); // O
    printf("e5 ? %d\n", F.find(e5)!=F.end()); // X

    //printf("%d\n", e3<e4);

    return 0;
}
```

```
If run this code, I got an error at "F.find(e5)!=F.end()" with following message.
"Debug Assertion Failed!. Expression: invalid operator < "

The condition of two edges of '(x,y), (p,q)' equality is 
 !(x < p || y < q) && !(p < x || q < y)

It can be '(x>=p && y>=q) && (p>=x && q>=y)'

I really don't know why assertion raised.
Is there something wrong?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comparison doesn't enforce a strict ordering. For example:

```
Edge e1;
Edge e2;

e1.v1 = 5;
e1.v2 = 4;

e2.v1 = 4;
e2.v2 = 5;

// e1 < e2 is true
// e2 < e1 is true
// So which one should we really trust? Neither, let's abort the program!
```

You need to make your `<` operator actually work like `<` should. If `e1 < e2` is true, then `e2 < e1` needs to be false.

I *think* this might be what you want, but beware that I haven't tested it:

```
return v1 < rhs.v1 || (v1 == rhs.v1 && v2 < rhs.v2);
```

This *should*, in theory, sort by `v1`, and use `v2` to break ties.

Comment: The easy way to write a correct `operator<` is to follow this pattern: `if (a != rhs.a) return a<rhs.a; if (b != rhs.b) return b<rhs.b; /*etc*/; return false;`

Comment: Another, easier, way to write a correct `operator<` is to follow this pattern: `return std::tie(e1.v1, e1.v2) < std::tie(e2.v1, e2.v2);`